# listview + imageview basic code example please

Tags: android, listview, imageview

I've been browsing all possible sites for ages and haven't found my needs yet. I rly need to find a code-example of a basic listview in android that lets me click on the items in the list and takes me to an imageview displaying an image (different for every item in the list). Please post a working samplecode for this as it's driving me mad that I can't figure it out :(

Comment: [**Here**](http://www.technotalkative.com/category/android/listview/) are tutorials for ListView, go through each tutorials from Bottom to Top manner, you will be defining custom adapter.

Comment: thanks, I'll check it out but I know how to make the actual listView, what I'm having troubbles with is displaying different images in the imageView depending on what list item I click, see my code below to get a better understanding of what I actually am asking for since my question was kinda vague, still seems like useful tutorials and will definitely check em out :)

Comment: yes i got it, whenever you click on a particular list item, you want to display that clicked item in another page. And in that page, you want to display image accordingly. For the same, you can create `ArrayList<Objects>` so that whenever you click a particular item, you can easily fetch that positioned item from that ArrayList.

Comment: Oh, I never thought of that before, I'll experiment some with it thanks, but in that scenario what would I put in the image.setImageResource to get the selected item from my list?

Comment: you should use Image URL to store image resource.

Comment: Okay, well this is getting a bit too complicated for me as I'm new to this android thing, so if anyone got like a tutorial or sample code or whatever to show me how to do that I'd like to know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to go into detail about creating the ListView or setting an adapter or any of that stuff, there's plenty of other examples on the Web to do that and your question isn't asking how to set a ListView adapter ;)

- Create an activity that extends `ListActivity`
- Create a layout for your new `ListActivity` and put a ListView in it
  (@+id/list) for my example
- What's in your list? idk, but lets say it's an ArrayList of strings

now override `onListItemClick` in your `ListActivity`

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
        if (l.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("LIST1"))
        {
                // Do something with it
        }
}
```

Alternatively, you don't need a ListActivity, you can set an `onItemClickListener`
e.g.

```
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new onItemClickListener()
{
    @Override protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've tried it now to do the entire app in just one class by doing what you said with the getItemAtPosition, and I don't get any errors, still when I run the app and press any of the items in the list the emulator just shuts down, no idea why :/

Comment: Post a stack trace and some code, what Objects are in your list?

Comment: Yes I will as soon as I can answer my own topic (in a coupple of hours), anyhow I've got an app working using an array list with strings, sending an intent to another class that connects with the imageView and then display an image. Allthough I've only got it to work for one of my items in the list so I'll post some code when I can answer this question, cause I rly need to make it show different images if I press different items in the list, and that part I still haven't figured out. Thanks for taking your time btw:)

Answer (score 0):

[check that link](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html)
all you need to do is change the `OnItemClickListener()` method

Answer (score 0):

Ok here's the code, first we got the list menu.

```
package item.list.lol;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Menu extends ListActivity {

String classes[] = {"startingPoint", "lol"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));

}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String pointer = classes[position];
    try{
    Class ourClass = Class.forName("item.list.lol." + pointer);
    Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);
    startActivity(ourIntent);
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

And then the class that handles the imageView

```
package item.list.lol;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class startingPoint extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
}}
```

And the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.67"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

As you see it can now only display an image if I press the first item in the list, I need a way to make it display different images if I click different items, any ideas?